# How to call contract method from specific address and private key without Metamask check

Tags: truffle, metamask, private-key, truffle-contract, ganache

Good morning,

I need to known how call contract method in javascript from specific address(and relative private key) without the check of Metamask.
I explain better.

This is an example of js code, it works but every time i call the method, Metamask ask the check and i need to iterate this function.

```
func: function() {

  App.contracts.Bidder.deployed().then(function(instance) {
    return instance.addBid(1, 10, 1, { from: address });
```

So I ask if there is a way to do this automatically inserting the private key in the code like the address.

This is for a local blockchain with truffle and ganache.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, if you sign your transaction and send it with [eth.sendRawTransaction](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethsendrawtransaction), there's an example in the documentation how to sign it using ethereumjs-tx and your private key.

Comment: Thanks, I have 2 questions: how can I sing and call a specific method as raw transaction? And what is the role of ethereumjs-tx here? Thank you very much.

Comment: To sign a transaction you need to [RLP](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/RLP) encode it, ethereumjs-tx will properly RLP encode a transaction and has a function to sign it. With web3 v1 you have a function [encodeABI](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#methods-mymethod-encodeabi) that you can use to format a function call in a message suitable for the data field of a transaction.